# Creating Buttons according to id

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Hello everyone**

```
con.Close();
            int buttoncounter= -1;
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from buttons", con);
                con.Open();
                buttoncounter = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
                con.Close();
            }
```

i count how much row i have on my database

```
for (int i = 1; i < buttoncounter; i++)
        {

            var buttonmenu = new Button
            {

                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 100,
                Margin = 5,
                CornerRadius = 15,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 192),

            };
            con.Close();
            buttonmenu.Clicked += butonmenu;
            buttons.Children.Add(buttonmenu);
            if (con.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand getir = new SqlCommand("select * from butonlar where id = '" + i.ToString() + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = getir.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                buttonmenu.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                con.Close();
                break;
            }
```

I create buttons with this method, lets think that we have 4 values in `buttons`. if user delete row 2 then it will be 1,3,4 and program will create 4 buttons, and 2. button's name will be empty,I should prevent the creation of the empty button

**id is not pk**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: as i wrote "I should prevent the creation of the empty button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**guys i solved the problem**

code updated:

```
SqlCommand getirme = new SqlCommand("select * from butonlar where id = '"+i.ToString()+"'", baglanti);
                SqlDataReader okumasa = getirme.ExecuteReader();
                while (okumasa.Read())
                {
                    value = okumasa.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    break;

                }
                // check is value is empty before creating button
                if (value == i.ToString())
                {
                    var buttonmenu = new Button
                    {
```

`if (value == i.ToString())` before that it was **set to detect which record is null**, but now, **it compares `id` and `i`** and **if matches** with `id` it creates button.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent creating a button when the Text is null, you will need to rearrange your logic a bit to execute the query BEFORE you create the button

```
var value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();

// check is value is empty before creating button
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
  var buttonmenu = new Button
  ...
}
```

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Are you resetting the value of check each time?

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question.  The way your code is structured if you don’t clear checked each time it will still have the value for the prior button, causing the logic to fail.  If you’re still having problems you need to edit your question to include the revised version of your code